# Am I correct in assuming that the HTML5 data-* attribute is not part of a POST request?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, custom-data-attribute

Say I have the following html: `<input id="food" data-id="28" value="pizza"></input>`
If I wrap the above in a form and do a post, should data-id and it's associated value be sent to the server? Or... are data-* attributes only usable on the client in JS or CSS?

Comment: You're correct, data attributes are not included in a post request.

Comment: So, I need to use JS to update, say a hidden input on the page, in order to get that to the server... Ok.  Thanks.

Comment: If you really wanna use those values you can create a Ajax call in jQuery and send those values with that. But just like Adam said, you cant use data attributes in a form

Comment: Rather than hidden inputs, if you're using JS you can fetch the data attributes, inject them into a concatenated string, and then pass it to with the AJAX call. I could write up something in jQuery if that's what you're using?

Comment: I wasn't going to use jQuery, just plain js, but hey, what would be the form for both?